# Regular expression to not allow users to enter NA or N/A or na or n/a

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a text box and users are entering na rather than supplying the specified data. How can explicitly not allow them to enter na in the field? I want to use an asp regularexpressionvalidator.

Comment: If the field has a specific format (phone #s, dates) then check that the input matches that format.  Otherwise rejecting N/A will just cause them to enter some other garbage.  No regex will make people give you info they don't want to give out.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?!\s*n\s*/?\s*a\s*$).*
```

will match (and return the input string) if the user enters anything except `n/a` and fail otherwise. All the variations in your questions are covered if you select case-insensitive matching (in .NET, this is done using the option `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`). Also, any amount of whitespace will be ignored so the user can't simply type `n  /   a`.

Comment: Problem here is that this also matches corn/anonymous

Comment: @Ryan Pedersen: How is this a problem? It is supposed to match anything except `n/a`, so corn/anonymous is a legal match.

Comment: AFAIK, RegularExpressionValidator doesn't accept RegexOptions arguments like the Regex constructors do.  You would have to use the inline modifier, `(?i)`, but then your validator could only run on the server; JavaScript doesn't support inline modifiers.

Comment: The problem is that this is only suppose to match "NA" or "N/A". So corn/anonymous might be a valid response to the question but it would not be allowed with this expression. It is close for sure and might be close enough but it could match things that it is not intended to match.

Comment: @Ryan Pedersen: No, this regex matches *anything except* "NA", "N/A" etc. Why do you think it would match corn/anonymous?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I stand corrected. The express does just what it should do. I tested this out in ASP.NET too and it works there with no issues. Good answer, sorry I about not recognizing it.

Comment: @PateeGutee: What if you use the inline modifier instead? ...`.Matches(@"(?i)^(?!\s*n\s*/?\s*a\s*$).*"`...

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex to solve this when you can solve it with a simple if statement?

```
if (input.ToLower().Trim() != "na" && input.ToLower().Trim() != "n/a")
{
    // Continue processing
}
```

Comment: Valid option but the regex is the solution chosen because they are using regularexpressionvalidator in ASP.NET. This really isn't the answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Ryan makes a good point - but if you're dead-set on using regex, this should do the trick (make sure you mark it as case insensitive):

`^n\/?a$`

Comment: This also matches corn/anonymous

Comment: Right, whoops - thanks for the heads-up. I've added start/end markers to the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitivity can be toggled by ?i: token, so the resulting regex can be like that:

```
(?i:^n\/a$)
```

**Update**: added parentheses after Alan's comment.

Comment: this is not a valid regex for asp.net. When I put it into a web page using RegularExpressionValidator I get the following error: parsing "?i:^n\/a$" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Comment: The correct syntax for inline modifiers is either `(?i:^n/a$)` or `(?i)^n/a$`, but see my comment to Tim's answer about using them.  (Also, `/` has no special meaning in regexes.  It only needs to be escaped if it's being used as the regex *delimiter*, but that's not an issue in .NET.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with RegularExpressionValidator because it will error when the pattern is not matched. There is no way to invert the RegularExpressionValidator to give an error condition when the pattern is matched.

You can use a CustomValidator to get this done and [4 Guys From Rolla wrote an tutorial on how to do this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx) a while ago or you can get some 3rd part validators like those from [Peter Blum](http://www.peterblum.com/DES/Home.aspx).

Before you invest to much time in it you should consider the comment from @bemace. If you do implement this you will only get a new kind of "garbage in" instead of n/a.