# FluentValidation with Regular Expression not allowing N/A or NA Ignoring Case and White Space

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I use `FluentValidation` in my ASP.NET MVC app and for some fields to not allow users to enter `N/A` and its variants.

I found Tim's answer in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413717/regular-expression-to-not-allow-users-to-enter-na-or-n-a-or-na-or-n-a) somewhat helpful but not exactly what I'm looking for. It does work but I don't want to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as validation using options like this seems to only happen server-side.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Question01)
    .Matches(@"^(?!\s*n\s*/?\s*a\s*$).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .WithMessage("Invalid answer.");
```

I am looking for a pure regex solution (not using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`) ignoring case and white spaces to allow anything except `N/A`, `N / A`, `NA`, `N A`, `n/a`, `n / a`, `na`, `n a`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution does work:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Question01)
    .Matches(@"^(?!\s*[Nn]\s*/?\s*[Aa]\s*$).*")
    .WithMessage("Invalid answer.");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match exactly those values and not allow combinations with upper and lower case mixed, you could list them all using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

**Note** that `\s` also matches a newline.

If you want to allow all except this pattern, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is on the right is not this pattern and an inline modifier `(?i)` or `(?i:`

```
^(?!(?i:n */? *a)$).+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `(?i:` Inline modifier for case insensitive match
  - `n */? *a` match `n`, optional `/` surrounded with optional spaces
  - `)$` Close inline modifier and assert end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char 1+ times
- `$` Assert end of the string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%28%3fi%3an+*%2f%3f+*a%29%24%29.%2b%24&i=N%2fA)

If this should also work in Javascript, you could use a character class as inline modifiers are not supported.

```
^(?!(?:[nN] *\/? *[aA])$).+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sc8lMr/1)

Comment: He said ignore whitespaces, so I'm assuming n /a and n  /     a would also both match

Comment: @andyb952 You are right, not sure the upper and lowercase can be mixed though. I have updated it using spaces and uppercase and lowercase variations.

Comment: Yes, the "etc" in my question means any variants including mix of lower and upper case while ignoring white spaces.

Comment: You could use the second pattern in that case.

Comment: I tried your solution: `RuleFor(x => x.Question01).Matches(@"^(?i:n */? *a)$").WithMessage("Invalid answer.");` and it is doing the opposite. It's not allowing correct answers but allowing `N/A` and its variants.

Comment: Is your errormessage ok? Else try `(?i)^(?:n */? *a)$`

Comment: Still doing the opposite. `FluentValidation` displays the error message when given condition is not satisfied. Using your suggested regex, it allows `N/A` and not any correct answers which is the opposite of what is required.

Comment: @PateeGutee I see, I have updated the answer with a negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks it works now. However, for some reason, it works server-side only. The solution that I just posted works even client-side. As soon as I type `N/A` or any of its variants validation message appears right away.

Comment: @PateeGutee If you want to use this pattern with Javascript, then you could use a character class matching either an upper or a lowercase character as Javascript does not support inline modifiers `(?i)` or `(?i:`  For example `^(?!(?:[nN] *\/? *[aA])$).+$` See https://regex101.com/r/Sc8lMr/1

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match any variation on N/A, n/a, NA, na

Ignoring all whitespaces between N -> A and N -> / and / -> A

> \s*

For case insensitivty

> ?i:

End Result:

```
^(?i:n\s*/?\s*a)$
```

Comment: It's doing the opposite. When used in `FluentValidation`, it is allowing `N/A` and its variants and not allowing correct answers.